# How can I create a drop down list which can be filtered by another cell's value?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have an excel sheet that our salesman need to use for order requests.  I have created a drop down for descriptions and to auto-populate the daily weekly and monthly rental rates.

There are multiple branches that all use same equipment but have different rental rates. How can I achieve the proper rates when a choice is made in the drop down?

Worksheet A has a cell that allows the user to select the Branch.

Worksheet B contains rows of equipment choices:

Cat
Class
Item Description
Branch
Daily Price
Weekly Price
Monthly Price

I've been able to work with my IT guy a little, and he was able to get the rates to pull in using the formula , however he said he can only get this to work by saving a new file order sheet/excel file for each branch?

=IF($L18 <>"",INDEX(Sheet1!$D$2:Sheet1!$D$200,MATCH($L18,Sheet1!$H$2:Sheet1!$H$200,0)),"")

Any help in getting this "automated" would help... Hopefully this explains things further?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what you have tried tried, how the data is arranged, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the INDIRECT function to solve this.

here's what I did:

create a range "BranchList" containing "East" and "West".

Create a range for item numbers.

Create a range for "East" and for "West".
These ranges contain a list of item numbers and their corresponding rates for the branch.  Their range names must correspond to the "BranchList" names.

In cell A2, create the drop-down for the branch choice.

In cell A6, create the drop-down for the item number choice.

And then, the kicker:
in cell B6, put the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A6,INDIRECT(A2),2)
```

The `INDIRECT` command looks up cell A2 and treats it as a reference.  So when I select the East branch in cell A2, my command becomes `VLOOKUP(A6, EAST, 2)` and so it looks in the EAST range and retrieves the correct rates for the East branch.  If I select the West branch in cell A2, my lookup turns into `VLOOKUP(A6, WEST, 2)` and therefore retrieves the correct rates for the West branch.